# How to subscribe to the Azure SignalR service in a front-end Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I'm very new to SignalR and I'm trying to understand how to create a simple frontend application that gets notified using [Azure SignalR Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/).

I already have a server that uses the [Azure SignalR REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-rest-api) to send messages to an Azure SignalR service.

How do I get this massages in my Javascript frontend application?

Answer (score 0):

- To use signaIIr in front end you can use `hubconnectionbuider` class, this class is used to create instances of `hubconnection` which itself is used to communicate with the signalIR.
- The `hubconnection` instance communicate with signalIr by waiting for communication from the signalIr service.
- To achieve this first we need to start service connection using `startasync` function then use the `on` function to listen to signalIr service and `stopAsync` function to stop the service connection.

Refer this [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on hubconnection and this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/real-time-angular-11-application-with-signalr-and-net-5/) by Sarathlal  Saseendran on this specifically for angular js

Here is a [sample](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/signalr/using-signalr-in-asp-net-core-react-to-send-messages) by david grace on this specifically for react js .